# many to many hibernate mapping, with limitations

Tags: java, hibernate

i have two objects, linked through a third table in a many-to-many link.
it is mapped the following way in one object:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "PMSCampaignPublisher", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "publisherId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "campaignId") })

and this way in the other object:
@ManyToMany(cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "PMSCampaignPublisher", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "campaignId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "publisherId") })
```

i'd like to add a boolean flag in one of the object, so when trying to get the other objects it will be limited by this boolean flag. i didn't find a way to do it - is it possible at all?

Comment: Do it in an HQL or `Criteria` query. E.g. with HQL, select campaigns `from Campaign c where c.publisher.boolval=true`. Hibernate will generate the joins for you. You can find many references for HQL and `Criteria` on Google. I prefer `Criteria`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate has the @Where and @WhereJoinTable clauses you can use to filter collections.

See 2.4.6.1:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/